# Sorting collections within objects using Comparator and functions

Tags: java, lambda, comparator

I have the below method, and would like to add another field to the comparison, however I am finding it difficult to include.

```
 private static int daoComparator(EDao eDao1, EDao eDao2) {
    return Comparator.comparing((EDao eDao) -> eDao.getObjectA().getStatus())
            .thenComparing(EDao::getUpdatedDate)
            .thenComparing(EDao::getCreatedDate)
            .thenComparing((EDao eDao) -> eDao.getObjectA().getId())
            .compare(eDao1, eDao2);
}
```

Within `EDao` class, there is `ObjectA`, and within `ObjectA`, there is a `Collection<ObjectB>`. Within `ObjectB` there is an `Enum` of type `String` which I need to retrieve and sort within the above `daoComparator`. How can I update my method to retrieve and sort this `String` `Enum`? It also needs to be the first comparison. `Comparator` is from `java.util` package.

```
public class EDao
{
    private ObjectA objectA;
    private Date updatedDate;
    private Date createdDate;
}

public class ObjectA 
{   
    private String id;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private String status;
    private Collection<ObjectB> objectB;
}

public class ObjectB
{ 
    // field I want to retrieve for sorting
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    String RegStatus status;
}
```

Comment: There's a collection of string (*which by the way **lucks the name** in your code*) associated with an instance of `EDao` through `ObjectA`, can you explain how exactly do you want to compare `EDao` instances based on these collections?

Comment: And `Comparator` should be a `public static` field, there's no need to generate a new comparator for every comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to retrieve the status', I just need to handle the scenario where `ObjectB` could be null.

```
 private static int daoComparator(EDao eDao1, EDao eDao2) {
    return Comparator.comparing((EDao eDao) -> eDao.getObjectA().getObjectB().stream().findFirst().get().getStatus())
     .thenComparing((eDao eDao) -> eDao.getObjectA().getStatus())
     .thenComparing(EDao::getUpdatedDate)
     .thenComparing(EDao::getCreatedDate)
     .thenComparing((EDao eDao) -> eDao.getObjectA().getId())
     .compare(eDao1, eDao2);
```

Comment: Although your answer is correct, it probally will not help other programmers much.
You can find a better and reusable solution when thinking more "object-orientated" and implement the interface java.lang.Comparable in all your three classes.